# I am trying to create a spring BATCH JOB reading from mongoDB then saved to a file.

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-batch

However, I can not find any tutorials or anything remotely close to what I am looking for. I was hoping someone would know how I can start this process or find a good resource to complete my project.

Answer (score 0):

I found alot, following are "read from db and write to file":

http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/batch/70976-detailed-steps-to-read-from-a-database-and-write-into-a-csv-file

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring_batch/spring_batch_mysql_to_flat_file.htm

And here is Spring Data With MongoDB:

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-mongodb-tutorial

Hope you can combine them and complete your task.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time. A lot of great info.

Answer (score 0):

To read form mongo, you can use the `MongoItemReader`. To write to a file, you can use the `FlatFileItemWriter`.

Then, you need to create a job with a chunk-oriented step that uses the mongo reader and the flat file item writer.

You can find examples of how to do this in the [spring-batch-samples](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/tree/master/spring-batch-samples) module.

Hope this helps.